# SQL Escape Charater and C# (Apostrohe followed by qoute) (Using ExecuteNonQuery)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, escaping

I have the following problem

`Delete FROM PV_ExplorerView WHERE Contains(File_Path,'"\\fileserver\folder\folder\Unkown.png"')`

How I write this in C#? When using `SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()` i get a syntax error, I guess since it adds " to the quotes.

My c# looks like this

```cs
List<System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter> myParams = new List<System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter>();
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter myDBparam = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@fPath", deletePath);
myParams.Add(myDBparam);

MyDBClass.ExecuteNonQuery("Delete FROM PV_ExplorerView WHERE File_Path Contains(File_Path,'\"@fPath\"')",myParams);
```

When getting the raw value of my string it looks something like this

```
SqlStr = "Delete FROM PV_ExplorerView WHERE File_Path Contains(File_Path,'\"@fPath\"')"
```

With Select and DataAdpater.Fill() O have no problem... i am using mainly the " qoutes that the contains functions do not ignore whitespaces in my path cell, when searching.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: SQL Server single quotes are used to indicate a string.  If you have 123 it is a number and if you have '123' it is a string.  In c# you already have a string so you do not need the single quotes.

Comment: @jdweng Make sense i tried `MyDBClass.ExcuteNonQuery("Delete FROM PV_ExplorerView WHERE File_Path Contains(File_Path,\"@fPath\")",myParams)` still not working, i need the " qoutes that the contains function of the MSSQL-Server do not ignore whitespaces, since i had the problem when selecting i got syntax error. Putting my path into quotes helped it.

Comment: `MyDBClass.ExecuteNonQuery("Delete FROM PV_ExplorerView WHERE Contains(File_Path,'\"@fPath\"')", myParams)` The syntax is `WHERE CONTAINS(...` and you need single quotes for the text (and possibly double quotes *inside* that)

Comment: @Charlieface yes thats right how i do that? `MyDBClass.ExecuteNonQuery("Delete FROM PV_ExplorerView WHERE Contains(File_Path,'\"@fPath\"')", myParams)` does not work, but i need the quotes "fPath " so it does not ignore whitespaces of the value, since sometimes my file_path contains that.

Comment: Syntax seems valid to me https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=69517d1af62759622d4e76b8a1d0935f

Comment: Ohhh yes, thanks so much, i did not saw it that you meaned the File_Path before ... ergh work is killing me